# Delayer JDBCMessageStore

Tags: spring-integration

I have tied a `JDBCMessageStore` to the `Delayer` component so that we can avoid losing messages on a system failure as compared to the in memory `MessageStore` which is wiped out on system shutdown.

I have created tables `INT_MESSAGE`, `INT_MESSAGE_GROUP` and `INT_GROUP_TO_MESSAGE`. On testing, looks like the tables are getting inserted. 
I see that the `INT_MESSAGE`, `INT_MESSAGE_GROUP` are empty after the `Delayer` picks up the message, is this the functionality? To remove messages from the persistent store once the `Delayer` picks up these? I still see an entry in `INT_GROUP_TO_MESSAGE` with `COMPLETE`, `LAST_RELEASED_SEQUENCE` and `MARKED` all 0, are these used?. The `UDPATED_DATE` column is updated every time there is an entry and exit of a message. How do I know what are the states a message goes through for a Spring component tied to a persistent message store.

Which column does the `Delayer` look into to pick up messages after system recovery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I see that the INT_MESSAGE, INT_MESSAGE_GROUP are empty after the Delayer picks up the message, is this the functionality?

Yes, it is. The `DelayHandler` performs :

```
if (removeDelayedMessageFromMessageStore(message)) {
        if (!(this.messageStore instanceof SimpleMessageStore)) {
            this.messageStore.removeMessagesFromGroup(this.messageGroupId, message);
        }
        this.handleMessageInternal(message);
    }
```

therefore it is fully correct that message are removed from the DB after their usage.

`COMPLETE`, `LAST_RELEASED_SEQUENCE` and `MARKED` are used for `Aggregator` and `Resequencer`, but to save some place on the DB they all use the same  tables for `MessageStore` abstraction.

> The `UDPATED_DATE` column is updated every time there is an entry and exit of a message.

That's correct, because all the message in `DelayHandler` are grouped via its `id`: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#delayer-message-store. See `GROUP_KEY` column. It must be an `UUID.toString()` representation.

> How do I know what are the states a message goes through for a Spring component tied to a persistent message store.

There are no states. Message is stored in the DB, if it requires a delay. When the task comes for an execution, it performs a pick up and delete for that message. In this case the `group` record is updated as well.

> Which column does the Delayer look into to pick up messages after system recovery?

There is no such a tag. If message is in the store, it must be rescheduled for delay or return to the `outputChannel` because of expired delay timeout.

Therefore `DelayHandler` just reads all the message in the store after application startup:

```
for (final Message<?> message : messageGroup.getMessages()) {
        getTaskScheduler().schedule(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // This is fine to keep the reference to the message,
                // because the scheduled task is performed immediately.
                long delay = determineDelayForMessage(message);
                if (delay > 0) {
                    releaseMessageAfterDelay(message, delay);
                }
                else {
                    releaseMessage(message);
                }
            }

        }, new Date());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Artem Bilan ! That's a detailed explanation which answers each question.

Comment: Hi Artem ! I have another question on the above.What if there is a message sitting in the JDBCMessageStore and the same message comes into the store before the delay interval has expired? Will we have 2 records and both sent across after their delay? Or there is a validation to overwrite/discard against the MESSAGE_ID?

Comment: The same message will be discarded by the DB constraint: constraint `MESSAGE_PK primary key (MESSAGE_ID, REGION)` on the `INT_MESSAGE` table.